# Does the command WATCH in Redis behave in the same way as volatile variable in Java?

Tags: java, redis, concurrency, volatile

I'm a bit hesitating in terms of how Redis transaction concept works.

As fas as I know transaction is list of command between `multi` and `exec` which is not executed immediately, but this deferred until `exec` will be called.

Let's assume that I put some value to Redis in atomic way:

```
MULTI
  get current value and increment
EXEC
```

Exectly at this momemt new thread comes and try to read value which was stored as shown above. Does it mean that this value will be unavailable until transaction will be finished and this thread will perform his logic in wrong way since this value has not been read ?

And in order to give possibility for thread to read this value meanwhile transaction is running I need to use `WATCH` which does definitely the same as volatile variable - stores access to value which is kind of blocked by transactions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the Redis Transactions documentation - https://redis.io/topics/transactions.

First, you need to recall that Redis is single threaded.
When you send a command after calling `MULTI` Redis doesn't execute the command and just `QUEUED` it.
Only, when `EXEC` is call then the main thread (the only execution thread) is running all the `QUEUED` commands in the transaction. So, no other client can read part of the traction.

As for `WATCH`, it's not used as `volatile` but only as an indicator for Redis that if this key was changed between the call to `WATCH` and the call to `EXEC` the transaction shouldn't fail not committed.

Using `WATCH` one can assure that any reads done between the `WATCH` and `MULTI` are still valid by the time `EXEC` is called.

Comment: Thank you Guy. So basically from you response I understand that I can use Redis as helper to restrict too frequent requests to my API, keeping time and user id in Redis cache

Comment: if you're looking to build a rate limiter, you can find many examples online e.g. 
https://developer.redis.com/howtos/ratelimiting/